# How can I use custom fields instead of the page titles returned by wp_list_pages?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to use a side menu to navigate when a page has child pages.
What I have currently is nearly perfect, but instead of using the titles of the child pages in the menu, I want to use a custom field 'sidebar_title'.

I'm currently running this function that I found:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '
        <nav class="sidenav">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a></li>'
                   .$childpages.
               '</ul>
        </nav>';
    }
    return $string;
}
```

This gives me this result:

```
<nav class="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page URL">Parent Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="page URL">Child Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="page URL">Child Page</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I just need to know how I can replace the title of the child pages with my custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get_pages` function so you can have control over the layout. the function you are using now is `wp_list_pages` which is based on `get_pages` so you do not need to change anything in your main request. So your full code will look like this:

```
$childpages = get_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {
   $string = '<nav class="sidenav"><ul><li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a></li>'

   foreach( $childpages as $page ) {
      $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_post_meta($page->ID, 'sidebar_title', true) . '</a></li>';
   }

   $string .= '</ul></nav>';

   return $string;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the syntax error. 
The code returns a lot more than I need though.
The first <li> I get is always the current page, then I see the results I want underneath. 
If I inspect the resulting code though, there are a bunch of unfilled <li> elements for other unrelated pages that also use the same custom field.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Might be what you meant in the first place. I'll post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have done the trick.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = get_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
        $childpages = get_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '<nav class="sidenav"><ul><li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">'.get_field(sidebar_title, ($post->post_parent)).'</a></li>';

        foreach( $childpages as $page ) {
        $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_post_meta($page->ID, 'sidebar_title', true) . '</a></li>';
    }

    $string .= '</ul></nav>';

    return $string;
}}
```

Comment: Glad to help. But you need to fix your code. You always return $string but you should return it only if the page has children. Otherwise, when the page has no children you return a string variable which starts only in if statement. Basically, you will get a PHP warning.

Comment: I'm not experiencing any issues with it, even on pages that have no children. No warnings in the console.

Isn't $string only being returned if a value is set for $childpages, which I'm guessing isn't assigned a value if there are no child pages? If I understand the code correctly, at least.